# RegEx for transforming a path graph

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regular-language, dfa

Pretty much we are asked to find a regular expression for the DFA as shown in the link attached above. What I've gotten down is the path from s0 to s2 which I think is (a(b(ab)*) and s0 to s4 which I think is b(a(ba)*). But I'm not sure how to include the path from s1 to s3.

[image: DFA Image Problem]

I tried taking a look at this [link](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14sp/kleene.pdf), to try and understand how they transformed their DFA into a regular expression, but I'm still lost.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the funny problem!

We need to break it down into parts:

```
(a{s1 to end})|(b{s3 to end})
```

{s1 to end} is :

```
{s1 to s1}*{s1 to end without coming back to s1}
```

{s1 to s1} is:

```
(a(ab)*b)|(ba)
```

{s1 to end without coming back to s1} is:

```
b|(aa(ba)*)
```

{s3 to end} is :

```
{s3 to s3}*{s3 to end without coming back to s3}
```

{s3 to s3} is:

```
(b(ba)*a)|(ab)
```

{s3 to end without coming back to s3} is:

```
a|(bb(ab)*)
```

Then we can put it all together:

```
(a{s1 to s1}*{s1 to end without coming back to s1})|(b{s3 to s3}*{s3 to end without coming back to s3})
```

which finally gives:

```
(a((a(ab)*b)|(ba))*(b|(aa(ba)*)))|(b((b(ba)*a)|(ab))*(a|(bb(ab)*)))
```

EDIT: fixed an error that has slipped into the last expression